# Regex to catch strings with only 2 digits

Tags: regex

I have searched for similar questions, and even though I found several answers, none seams to work. I have a list of strings

```
Z189
I142
M395
L210
V467
M203
Q277
Q461
Y440
S250
M162
Q96
22Q
W148
Q72
T22T
22TWE22
12E34
```

and I need a regex to find only strings holding only 2 digits (not more or less). So in this case:

`Q96, 22Q, Q72, T22T`

my failed attempts include:

```
\D\d{2}\D
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

Comment: Try `^(?:\D*\d){2}\D*$`? Or [`^\D*(?:\d\D*){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZOBCyi/1).

Comment: Do the two nubers have to be together (T22) or can the be split (2T2)?

Comment: @Kokogino I frankly don't know, I haven't thought about it. Can u think a solution for each case?

Comment: If 2 digits are continuous then use: `^\D*\d{2}\D*$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RMG8VU/4)

`\D*` makes sure anything before your first digit isn't another digit.

`(\d)` captures your first digit.

`\D*` makes sure there is no other digits between your two digits.

`(\d)` captures your second digit.

`\D*` makes sure anything after your second digit isn't another digit.

Comment: you can validate the regexpr above here:
https://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4/113

Comment: You can replace `[^\d]` by `\D`.

Comment: @Kokogino Edited it :)

Comment: the regexpr does not match for "1EER4TT"   "TT22"

Comment: @3p3ch3 Yes it does.

Comment: @3p3ch3 Your version isn't up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

This works well. Note the `global` and `multiline` flags.

```
/^[a-zA-z]\d{2}[a-zA-Z]*$/gm
```

Explanation: Start of line -> letter -> exactly two digits -> zero or more letters -> end of line

Answer (score 2):

To match a string that only contains 2 digits at any location, you may use

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOBCyi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - any 0+ chars other than digits
- `(?:\d\D*){2}` - 2 repetitions of:

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `\D*` - any 0+ chars other than digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention if the digits had to be sequential, but all of your examples had them as such. The following RegEx will only match lines that contain exactly two sequential digits:

```
^\D*\d{2}\D*$
```

Explained:

- `^` matches the beginning of the String
- `\D*` matches any non-digit zero or more times
- `\d{2}` matches exactly two digits
- `\D*` matches any non-digit zero or more times
- `$` matches the end of the String

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://regexr.com/3lvkm)